# (Vielleicht umgangsprachliches) deutsches Wort: Unannehmlichkeiten verursachen

Tags: single-word-request, slang

*An alle, deren Deutsch besser ist, als meins (ca. alle): Fühlt euch frei signifikante Änderungen vorzunehmen, wenn es besser klingt.*

Auf Englisch habe ich manchmal den Begriff

> letting him/her suck (*)

gehört. Das bedeutete in diesem umgangssprachlichen Kontext ungefähr Folgendes:

> Jemand anderen absichtlich unterschiedliche, kleinere oder größere Schwierigkeiten verursachen, oft mit der Absicht, seine/ihre Lage
>   schlechter zu machen.

Eine sexuelle Bedeutung hatte es eigentlich nicht.

Drei Beispiele:

- Wenn man in einem Hotel kostenlos salzige Backwaren essen darf, aber es kein Wasser gibt und die Getränke äußerst teuer sind.
- Wenn in einem Land die Mehrwertsteuer 27% oder die Benzinpreise bei 2.5 Euro pro Liter liegen.
- Wenn man am Arbeitsplatz Aufgaben gestellt bekommt, bei denen man keine Möglichkeit hat, sie zu lösen.

Gibt es ein deutsches Wort dafür? In Wörterbüchern habe ich keinen passenden Begriff gefunden. Es wäre auch gut, wenn es kein wirklich (genauer?)harter Begriff wäre.

(*) Es kam nicht aus einem muttersprachlichen Kontext, also es ist möglich, dass es kein korrektes Englisch ist.

Comment: Schwierigkeiten machen? Knüppel zwischen die Beine werfen? Für mich sind die ersten beiden Beispiele einerseits und das dritte andererseits sehr unterschiedlich, und ich sehe nichts, das für beides passen könnte.

Comment: @chrilu Afaik diese waren nicht die beste Beispiele. Vielleicht "Bananenschale unten die Füsse werfen" wäre ein besseres. Aber deine Version klingt mir schon auch sehr gut! Ich habe ungefähr an dieser Bedeutung gedacht.

Comment: @peterh, ich habe diverse kleine Fehler verbessert. Was meinst du denn mit "Es wäre auch gut, wenn es kein wirklich harter Begriff wäre."?

Comment: @iris Ich wollte sagen, daß ich möglicherweise die nicht harsche Wörter preferieren würde.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ich habe an unangenehmen Schwierigkeite gedacht (wie in den Beispiele), aber es würde mich eigentlich nicht überraschen, wenn "Unannehmlichkeit" oder "Ärger" in dieser Kontext besser passen würde.

Comment: @peterh naja ich bezog mich auf den Titel denn Unangenehmlichkeiten habe ich noch nie gehört. Schau mal ob meine Änderungen auch passen, Titel habe ich nicht verändert!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Mit einem bißchen Google Translate habe ich diese Wort-Version gefunden, wie klingt es?

Comment: @Iris Möglich. "To cause different problems for other people", würde ich auf English sagen (was vielleicht auch nicht am besten ist).

Comment: @peterh, harsch im Sinne von unfreundlich? Und ich denke "Unannehmlichkeiten" wäre das richtige Wort, oder?

Comment: Ich habe den Begriff im Titel "Unangenehmheiten" in "Unannehmlichkeiten" geändert. "Unangenehmheiten" gibt es nicht als Begriff.

Comment: Jemanden *bluten lassen* - Ist ein bisschen auf der "härteren" Seite, kommt aber mAn "to let so suck" ziemlich nahe.

Comment: @tofro: Bluten lassen finde ich recht gut. Antwort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ein anderer Begriff wäre: **schi­ka­nie­ren**. [Schi­ka­nie­ren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schikanieren) bedeutet

> jemanden mit kleinliche, böswilligen Quälereien (=Schikanen) ärgern.

Eine [Schikane](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schikane) ist eine:

> - [unter Ausnutzung staatlicher oder dienstlicher Machtbefugnisse getroffene] Maßnahme, durch die jemandem unnötig Schwierigkeiten bereitet werden
> - kleinliche, böswillige Quälerei

Eine Schikane ist nicht lustig, sondern bösartig und man kann z.B. gegen dienstliche Schikanen gerichtlich vorgehen.

Jemanden zu **[drangsalieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drangsalieren)**, zu **[tyrannisieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tyrannisieren)** oder jemandem **das Leben zur Hölle machen** sind noch extreme Begriffe für (andauernde, extreme) Quälereien.

Weniger extrem dagegen sind **[piesacken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/piesacken)** oder **[triezen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/triezen)**. Diese Begriffe, kann man auch nehmen wenn man **jemandem ("nur") absichtlich auf die Nerven geht**.

Comment: + für schikanieren, piesacken und triezen, die sind mir vorhin nicht eingefallen, aber jetzt wo Du sie angegeben hast fällt es mir wie Schuppen aus den Augen!

Comment: @Medi1Saif "Schuppen _von_ den Augen" oder (wohl als Verballhornung davon) "Schuppen _aus_ den Haaren" sind die stehenden Wendungen.

Comment: @Matthias Du hast recht "von" ist wohl die korrekte Ausdrucksweise, aber irgendwie habe ich mir "aus" angewöhnt oder beide Ausdrucksweisen aus Versehen gemixt!

Answer (score 5):

Ein in etwa äquivalenter Ausdruck dafür wäre wohl:

> Jemanden Steine in den Weg stellen (legen)

fällt mir spontan dazu ein. (Siehe [auch](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20Steine%20in%20den%20Weg%20legen&suchspalte[]=rart_ou))

**Synonyme** gibt es [hier](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Steine%20in%20den%20Weg%20legen):

> - behindern,
> - erschweren,
> - hemmen,
> - hindern,
> - hinderlich sein.

Aber natürlich geht auch

> - Schwierigkeiten machen/bereiten,
> - Unannehmlichkeiten bereiten.

Ist zwar nicht gefragt aber weitere Ausdrucksweisen wären:

> Jemanden das Leben schwer machen

oder

> Jemanden Salz in die [Suppe](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~das%20Salz%20in%20der%20Suppe&suchspalte[]=rart_ou)/[Wunde](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20Salz%20in%20die%20Wunde%20streuen%20/%20reiben&suchspalte[]=rart_ou) streuen

Ich dachte auch an:

Jemanden am ausgestreckten (oder langen) Arm verhungern lassen. Aber dass ist ja ohne aktiv zu werden. Also einfach die Hilfe verweigern.

Answer (score 2):

*Jemanden bluten lassen* kommt im Gebrauch und Sprachstil dem Original meiner Meinung nach am nächsten. Im Gebrauch meint man natürlich nicht, dass der Andere tatsächlich blutet, sondern dass er "leidet". Um das archaische Bild ein bißchen abzuschwächen, wird der Ausdruck oft mit *ganz schön* abgedämpft.

> Deutschland lässt bei einem Mehrwertsteuersatz von 27% seine Bürger ganz schön bluten.

oder

> Erst geben sie einem kostenlose Salzstangen, und dann lassen sie ihn bei den Getränken bluten.

Meinem Gefühl nach hat der Ausdruck auch das äquivalente Maß an Umgangssprachlichkeit zum Original (das ich i.Ü so noch nicht gehört habe)

Comment: Ich kenne diese Formulierung nur im monetären Kontext.

Comment: Ja, gebe ich dir teilweise recht - Wenn wir uns darauf einigen, dass "monetärer Kontext" ganz allgemein für einen Fall gilt, in dem man "für etwas bezahlen" muss - Auch im übertragenem Sinne. Z.B. auch ein schwer erkämpfter Sieg, den man mit vielen Gefallenen "bezahlen" muss.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde gerne noch vorschlagen:

> Ärger machen

und

> Jemanden in die Pfanne hauen

Comment: 1+ für das letztere!

Answer (score 0):

Mir fallen spontan zwei Formulierungen ein:

> jemanden an etwas verzweifeln lassen

und

> jemandem Schwierigkeiten machen